# Fancyhdr and hyperref - unwanted space before header

Tags: spacing, hyperref, fancyhdr, autoref

I'm writing a report in french. I'm using `hyperref`'s `autoref` for cross-references and I have redefined some of the names used by the function, such as Appendix and Figure, in my preamble.

I just noticed an unwanted spacing in my `fancyhdr` header; this space seems to increase and decrease in proportion to how many `\addto\extrasfrench...` instructions I use.

I have tried to look into the `hyperref.sty` file but I'm too novice to understand that level of LaTeX syntax.

The MWE below produces the unwanted space on the document's last page's header, and by commenting and de-commenting `\addto\extrasfrench...` instructions, one can see this space changing.

Can anyone help ?

Graphical description of the problem : the red arrow shows the variable spacing that I want to get rid of
[image: Red arrow indicates unwanted space]

MWE :

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt, french]{report}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

% géometrie de la page
\usepackage[
    headheight = 15.25pt, 
    left=2cm, 
    right=2cm, 
    top=2cm, 
    bottom=2cm, 
    showframe,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % permet de modifier les en-têtes
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% active les en-têtes et pieds de page
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}%
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\textsl{\leftmark}}% en-tête à gauche

%% <-- --------------------------------------------------------------- -->
%% <-- COMMENT OUT ONE AFTER THE OTHER AND NOTICE THE SPACE INCREASING -->
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addto\extrasfrench{%
    \def\appendixautorefname{annexe}
}
\addto\extrasfrench{%
    \def\figureautorefname{figure}
}
\addto\extrasfrench{%
    \def\equationautorefname{\'equation}
}
%% <-- --------------------------------------------------------------- -->

\begin{document}
    \part{Dummy part}

        \chapter{Dummy chapter}

            \section{Dummy section}
                Hi there
                \newpage
                Some text

\end{document}
```

Comment: you have spurious spaces after your definitions. Add a % after `{annexe}` and so on.

Comment: Dankeschön, @UlrikeFischer ! That did it. I just don't understand why the spurious spaces would be added even though I called neither `{annexe}` nor any of the two other.

Comment: But are calling in various places `\extrasfrench` (e.g. in the header there is an implicit \selectlanguage), and if this command contains `{annexe} \def...` you get a space.

Comment: I figured they would have to be called at some point without being used when I noticed that uncommenting them seemed to reduce the spacing. Great problem-solving skills ;-) thanks again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be answering my own question (again), thanks to user UlrikeFischer !

I forgot the `%` after the definitions for `autoref`. The new definitions should look like follows :

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addto\extrasfrench{%
    \def\appendixautorefname{annexe}%
}
\addto\extrasfrench{%
    \def\figureautorefname{figure}%
}
\addto\extrasfrench{%
    \def\equationautorefname{\'equation}%
}
```